# Getting the body text of a website from its URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the body text of a website, given its URL. I am able to obtain the DOM of the website as a string using the XMLHttpRequest API. However, I only want to have the text of the website (one you would obtain by doing Ctrl A) without the html/css tags.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var documentBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].textContent;

console.log(documentBody);
```

that should give you raw text.

Comment: The problem is, they didn't ask for the text content of the current document, they asked for the text content of a string received from XMLHttpRequests.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```js
new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, "text/html").body.textContent
```

although, if there are tags with style display none, they would still show.

Comment: Thank you. This code did give me the text inside the html tags of the body, but do you know if there is a way to obtain the text  of the website, i.e. the text that can be seen on the interface of the website and that you can manually obtain by cntrl-A-ing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the text inside html tags is most likely the text of the website, because for example, this method strips away script tags, and any more most likely would require some complex regexing. The only problem might be that it keeps new lines and a ton of whitespace, but displaying it to a user with html would again strip it away.

Comment: Oh I guess what's also included in the output is the text inside <script> tags which is not something that is displayed on the website. Is there a way to modify your command to include all tags inside the body except <script>? I believe that way we can extract the text displayed on the website.

Comment: I believe the JS in the <script> tags are already left alone.

Comment: For some reason I am getting the content inside <script> tags (like JS functions, etc.) when using your line of code.